# Optimize query with union

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have to optimize the following query, it takes too time to executed

```
SELECT Devis.Numero_Devis, 
       contrat.Numero_contrat, 
       Devis.Id_Devis, 
       contrat.ID_contrat 
FROM   (SELECT ID_contrat          AS Id_Devis, 
               Numero_contrat AS Numero_Devis 
        FROM   [sch_DM_LMI].Fact_IU_contrat AS contrat 
        WHERE  ( Code_Statut_Contrat = 'D' )) AS Devis 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [sch_DM_LMI].Fact_IU_contrat AS contrat 
                    ON Devis.Numero_Devis = contrat.Numero_contrat 
                       contratD contrat.Code_Statut_Contrat = '1' 
UNION 
SELECT 'Inconnu'                              AS Numero_Devis, 
       'Inconnu'                              AS Numero_contrat, 
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS Id_Devis, 
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS ID_contrat
```

I created th following index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Devis
ON [sch_DM_LMI].[Fact_IU_contrat] ([Code_Statut_Contrat])
INCLUDE ([ID_contrat],[Numero_contrat])
```

Here the execution plan:

[image]
How to optimize it?

Comment: Any execution plan?

Comment: Can you do UNION ALL instead of UNION?

Comment: If you do need to retain `UNION`, then what you're actually doing is is the same as putting `DISTINCT` in your first `SELECT`. Generally, if you do need to use `DISTINCT` for such a query, it normally means you have a problem with your joins (or design).

Comment: @jarlh I update my question with the execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT 'Inconnu'                              AS Numero_Devis, 
       'Inconnu'                              AS Numero_contrat, 
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS Id_Devis, 
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS ID_contrat
UNION ALL  -- NOT UNION    
SELECT Devis.Numero_contrat, 
       contrat.Numero_contrat, 
       Devis.ID_contrat, 
       contrat.ID_contrat 
FROM [sch_DM_LMI].Fact_IU_contrat devis LEFT JOIN
     [sch_DM_LMI].Fact_IU_contrat contrat 
     ON contrat.Numero_contrat = Devis.Numero_contrat AND
        contrat.Code_Statut_Contrat = '1' 
WHERE devis.Code_Statut_Contrat = 'D';
```

The only important change here is the change to `UNION ALL`.

Then for this query, you want indexes on `Fact_IU_contrat(Code_Statut_Contrat, Numero_contrat)` and `Fact_IU_contrat(Numero_contrat, Code_Statut_Contrat)` -- yes, both.  You can also include `id_contrat` in both indexes.